# What $TERM value can you use on a Nokia N810 so Vim's key mappings work properly?

Tags: shell, vim, maemo, hardware

I'm connected to a Nokia N810 Internet Tablet through ssh. The default `$TERM` value is `'xterm'` which causes all sorts of key bindings messes in Vim. Specifically the arrow keys, and home/end keys print out characters or change the case when not in editing mode.

Does anyone know a sane `$TERM` value to fix this problem, or some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setatakahashi is correct in that you'll need a .vimrc

From a Maemo / n810 perspective you'll want at least these (amongst any of your own personal) settings in your vimrc.

```
set nocompatible
set t_Co=256
set t_AB=^[[48;5;%dm
set t_AF=^[[38;5;%dm
```

The last three options set up the colours a bit more nicely within the vim on the tablet's terminal.

You get the `^[` by pressing `control-v escape`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .vimrc file in your home directory.

Comment: http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/starting.html#compatible-default

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried vt100?

Comment: Doesn't work, same results as TERM=xterm

Answer (score 0):

vt220 sometimes solves the problem for me